# Javascript: change value depending on HTML element's class on page

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The `<body>` tag in my pages has 3 possible combinations:

```
<body>
<body class="label1">
<body class="label2">
```

How can I output a different value for key `label_names` depending on which of these 3 combinations appears in the HTML of the page?

If it's `<body class="label1">` it should print:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
window.zESettings = {
  webWidget: {
    helpCenter: {
      filter: {
        label_names: 'label1'
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

If it's `<body class="label2">` it should print:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
window.zESettings = {
  webWidget: {
    helpCenter: {
      filter: {
        label_names: 'label2'
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

If it's just `<body>` it shouldn't print anything. I am not using JQuery, so only pure JS can be used. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd need to wait for the page load, then test the `classList`. If it's a match, you can write the script in the conditional

```
let thelabel
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  let b = document.querySelector('body');
  if (b.classList.contains('label1')) thelabel = 'label1';
  else if (b.classList.contains('label2')) thelabel = 'label2';
  if (thelabel) {
    window.zESettings = {
      webWidget: {
        helpCenter: {
          filter: {
            label_names: thelabel
          }
        }
      }
    };
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can  check whether `document.body.classList` contains a certain class via [`DOMTokenList.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains).

```js
var l = document.body.classList.contains('label1') ? 'label1' : document.body.classList.contains('label2') ? 'label2' : undefined;
if (l) {
  window.zESettings = {
    webWidget: {
      helpCenter: {
        filter: {
          label_names: l
        }
      }
    }
  };
}
console.log(zESettings.webWidget.helpCenter.filter.label_names);
```

```html
<body class="label1">
```

In expanded form:

```js
const c = document.body.classList;
var l;
if (c.contains('label1')) {
  l = 'label1';
} else if (c.contains('label2')) {
  l = 'label2';
}
if (l) {
  window.zESettings = {
    webWidget: {
      helpCenter: {
        filter: {
          label_names: l
        }
      }
    }
  };
}
console.log(zESettings.webWidget.helpCenter.filter.label_names);
```

```html
<body class="label1">
```